# Bash function, return bold text

Tags: bash, function, text, bold

I'm trying to write a simple bash function that returns bold text. The code I have written so far is:

```
function txt_bold() {<br>
    echo -e '\033[1m$1\033[0m$2'<br>
    tput sgr0<br>
}
```

When I write `txt_bold "This is bold" "And this in plain text"` it returns "$1$2" ($1 in bold). What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Hint: You should not edit the title to '[solved]', instead just tick the tick by the answer that answered your question. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/about to understand the basic principles of stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `"` instead of `'`.

```
function txt_bold() {
  echo -e "\033[1m$1\033[0m$2"
  tput sgr0
}
```

### Short

Within single quotes variables are not getting expanded.

### Long

Below's the bottom line of this article, which might help you understand it: [What’s the Difference Between Single and Double Quotes in the Bash Shell?](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/29980/whats-the-difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-the-bash-shell/)

#### Double Quotes

- Use when you want to enclose variables or use shell expansion inside a string.
- All characters within are interpreted as regular characters except for $ or ` which will be expanded on the shell.

#### Single Quotes

- All characters within single quotes are interpreted as a string character.